# Publish success but no changes on site?

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I have a site where I am getting:

[image: Description of publish success]

I had to do a full re-install where this previously all worked fine, and this is going to Azure.  I re-imported my publish settings from Azure and see this.  That looks good too so I assumed we were back to normal.

Except that the "Publish Succeeded" stuff, when I visit that actual URL I publish to (which I had to blur), none of my changes are there.

Any ideas?

I'm fully checked-in on the git branch and this runs fine locally.

Comment: are you sure it's not caching? Have you tried using incognito mode of your browser?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio It's not caching, not only incognito but I have "disable caching when dev tools are open" in both Chrome and the Chromium Edge and it's the same results with the dev tools open.  I've never seen anything like this and still haven't found a solution.

Comment: try deleting all files and push again, if it's still not working, then your build is not working properly

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I've tried deleting the publish profiles locally, if that's what you mean.  I don't understand what you mean by "build is not working properly", the screenshot shows it all succeeded and it works fine locally. By "deleting all files" do you mean on Azure?

Comment: Not sure if you are using pipelines or local build now. Anyway, clearly it's not producing the latest version or at least, this is not what you're uploading to Azure. Here's a good test: deploy it manually using FTP / Kudu, just to double check it's producing what you expect (the latest version). Assuming it is correct, then just solve your build. If it's still wrong, your compiling process is the problem

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Thanks for the assist, I was going to go the old-school FTP route (been in this game a long time) but I am going to use our Bitbucket setup to set up a publish through that.  We are using that on some of our other accounts and it's working fine so hopefully, for now, that will take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I understand you're using FTP to make changes to your Azure project. That's not really the best way of deploying an application in 2020, but for this particular issue that you're facing it doesn't matter what method you use.

The most likely scenario is that when you visit the URL you are being given a cached version of your website.

That can happen for multiple reasons:

1) Your browser stored a cached version of the website

2) You are using a CDN (content delivery network) such as Cloudflare, which most often comes with an enabled cache feature that ensures your users will get your static pages lightning fast

3) Your web application implements one or more caching procedures

If none of those is the case (ie: you have tried using incognito mode, you don't use a CDN and you haven't implemented a caching strategy) then you might need to double-check you have pushed to the correct branch and that the commits contain your recent changes.

EDIT: if you actually have everything checked, including that your Git repo is properly synchronized, then it might be worth trying a different deployment method -- normally it shouldn't affect the end result, but there is the possibility that the Microsoft Azure platform has certain hidden bugs - this being one of them.

Comment: It's not a caching issue I already commented on that above.  And yes, I am not going to continue to FTP this, that is my brute-force method in 2020 to get my changes up there, it's a method of last resort.  This worked perfectly fine prior to the re-install and I'm doing the exact same steps as I always have.  I don't understand why it says it "succeeded" when it clearly did not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thoroughly check the directories and stuff if its correct? most of the time issues like this are some minor errors like cache, wrong directories, and same output from previous files etc.

Answer (score -1):

Can it be that you're using "Debug" version instead of "Release" version?
Remember those hace differente folders for publishing.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer. Like "If you problen is ... then the solution is ... because ...". Otherwise this gives an impression of being a clarification question, for which a comment should be used instead of an answer post. Answers should be according to [answer], you can [edit] accordingly - or delete this post.